# JSON Where Clause on array of values with Query Builder

Tags: postgresql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, postgresql-json

Here is a JSON value in a `data` column of a `things` table:

```
{a: [{b: 1}, {b: 2}]}
```

I can get all `things` containing a `b` that is equals to 1 with a raw query like this:

```
select * from things where data @> '{ "a": [{"b": 1}] }';
```

I know we can run query with Laravel with JSON where clause with Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#json-where-clauses. I can write something like:

```
Thing::where('a->c', 'foobar');
```

But can I write a where to check if `a` contains `{b: 1}` just like in the raw query with Laravel's Query Builder?

Comment: It [seems that Laravel operates with](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7212b1e9620c36bf806e444f6931cf5f379c68ff/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/PostgresGrammar.php#L256) the `->` and `->>` operators in these "JSON where clauses" (which is not what you want to achieve). But the PostgresGrammar supports the `@>` and `<@` operators directly, so (in theory) you could write `->where('data', '@>', '{"a":[{"b":1}]}')`

Comment: @pozs I have just checked and your "theory" works! Thank you very much I did not think about this, I was writing a whereRaw query. You can post your comment as an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel ([as of now](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7212b1e9620c36bf806e444f6931cf5f379c68ff/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/PostgresGrammar.php#L256)) operates with the`->` and `->>` operators in these "JSON where clauses" (at least, for PostgreSQL). This is not what you want to achieve.

But the `PostgresGrammar` supports the `@>` and `<@` operators directly, so you could write:

```
Thing::where('data', '@>', '{"a":[{"b":1}]}')
```